# Select sql from 3 tables one to many

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Hello guys I have a question, My database has 3 tables

```
tags(id,name);

articles(id,title,smallimage,date,views);

tags_in_news(id,news_id,tag_id);
```

Now I want all article.titles attached to a tag.

I tried this but didn't help much:
My function:

```
public function get($obj_id)
{
    $this->load->database();
    $news = $this->db->query("SELECT 
                              t.name,
                              t.id,
                              a.title,
                              a.date,
                              a.views,
                              a.smallimage,
                              tin.id,
                              group_concat(a.title)
                              from tags_in_news tin
                              inner join tags t on t.id = tin.tag_id
                              inner join articles a on a.id = tin.news_id
                              and t.id = ?
                              group by t.id",array($obj_id));
    if ($news->num_rows())
    {
        $news = $news->result_array();
    }   
    else
    {
        $news = NULL;
    }

    return $news;
}
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => new tag
        [id] => 57
        [group_concat(a.title,a.views)] => Article1 52,Article3 51,Article3 56
    )

)
```

Comment: Could you more clear with the requirement please yeah? and Where is news table?

Comment: News table doesn't exist exist the Articles table

Comment: could you show me some sample output? or could you come up with diff words?

Comment: do you want all the article attached to a tags or all the tags attached to an article?

Comment: All articles to the tag

Comment: Ok would you mind putting a thumbs up and accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

All articles attached to a tag:

```
SELECT 
t.name tag,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.title) titles
FROM tags_in_news tin
INNER JOIN tags t ON t.id = tin.tag_id
INNER JOIN articles a ON a.id = tin.news_id
GROUP BY t.id;
```

One thing to note here is default length allowed for GROUP_CONCAT is 1024 chars.

So its recommended to get ids(if you suspect your concated value could go beyond the limit) as comma separated values and once you get ids you can do point queries afterwards.